# problem using ~/.aws/credentials and ~/.aws/config

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, environment-variables, boto3, credentials

i am trying to call S3 bucket using python script. i already create the credentials and config file too. using this kind of format in credentials:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id= my_key_id
aws_secret_access_key= my_secret_access_key
```

and config file:

```
[default]
region=ap-southeast-1
```

i already set my env variable too like this:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

i tried to run this script:

```
import boto3
# Create an S3 client
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
s3.put_object(Body='testing', Bucket='file-server-datalake', Key= 'test.txt')
```

and i got NoCredentialsError

is there any way to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4800344). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or press Ctrl+K, the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: Any details with the exception? Is the script running as the same user? The credentials file needs to have 0600 (or 0400?) permissions too

Comment: Do you actually have a space after the = sign in your credentials file?

Comment: thankyou guys, i dont know what happen but when i try to reload everything its just works